# Firebase Auth: Multi-Factor SMS [Error: [auth/operation-not-allowed]

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native

tl;dr On simulators, I can complete user enrollment with multi-factor (sms) using Firebase Auth, however on physical devices I receive `auth/operation-not-allowed`

**package.json**:

- "react": "^17.0.2"
- "react-native": "^0.67.5"
- "@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.3.0"
- "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^16.3.0"
- "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^16.3.0"

##### Configuration:

- GCP project linked to Firebase console has Identity Platform enabled
- GCP project, Firebase console: **Email Enabled, SMS Disabled, MFA (SMS) Enabled**
- Firebase console has two bundle IDs registered: (xxx.local, xxx.staging)
- One (1) APN Key from Appstore connect is linked on Firebase console to both bundle IDs
- xxx.staging has the correct Firebase GoogleService-Info.plist config
- xxx.staging has the Push Notifications and Background Changes capabilities enabled

Full Error (from Xcode, running on external device):

`2023-04-17 10:28:00.987600-0400 Wam (Staging)[576:10692] [javascript] 'auth/saga', '@watchPhoneEnrollment', 'MFA Enrollment failed', [Error: [auth/operation-not-allowed] This operation is not allowed. You must enable this service in the console.]`

[image: Firebase Console Auth - MFA Enabled]

I thought that the APN key not being configured in Firebase console may have been causing issues, but that seems to only apply for attesting to Firebase the validity of a multi-factor request.

After that, based on the error "check console", I would have ensured that my app is communicating with the correct project, and that multi-factor sms was enabled on both the firebase console, and gcp console.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr I had to enable both email and phone number, and multi-factor sms.

From the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/multi-factor

> 1. Enable **at least one provider that supports multi-factor authentication**. Every provider supports MFA, except phone auth, anonymous auth, and Apple Game Center.

Initially, I interpreted this to mean that your primary factor must be enabled on Firebase Authentication, and your Multi-Factor factor is enabled. However, upon enabling both Email, and Phone Number then allowed me to use Multi-Factor SMS authentication on Physical Devices.